# odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator)

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, odbc

The SQL statement below is throwing the error above. I do perhaps believe it's a syntax error. I am trying to execute this MS Access SQL statement using php Any help much appreciated.

```
$parm1 = "'TPMS'";
$parm3 = "'Gen 3'";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM archive where productfamily like $parm1 and where productmodel like $parm3 order by fullname asc";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have  multiple `where` in your query. Use single `where` like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM archive where productfamily like $parm1 and productmodel like $parm3 order by fullname asc";
```